# accessing dictionary through listbox

Tags: python, button, dictionary, tkinter, listbox

I am currently writing a GUI that allows you to display dictionary entries in a listbox, I want to be able to highlight certain ones and on button press perform some function with information contains in these entries.

But I am currently getting a `KeyError '0'`

Please see code (bewarned it's a bit lengthy):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk

from os import system

transDict = {}
transCount = 0

class TransMsg(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.canID   = ""
        self.msgType = ""
        self.canType = "" 
        self.tData0  = ""
        self.tData1  = ""
        self.tData2  = ""
        self.tData3  = ""
        self.tData4  = ""
        self.tData5  = ""
        self.tData6  = ""
        self.tData7  = ""

        self.timer   = 0
        self.DLC     = 0


class application:

    def __init__(self,window):

        self.window = window
        """Initialize the Application """
        self.IDbox = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.IDbox.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.IDbox.insert(0,"ID")
        self.IDbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.msgTypeBox = tk.Entry(window,width = 8)
        self.msgTypeBox.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.msgTypeBox.insert(0,"MSG Type")
        self.msgTypeBox.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.canTypeBox = tk.Entry(window,width = 8)
        self.canTypeBox.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.canTypeBox.insert(0,"Can Type")
        self.canTypeBox.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.tData0Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData0Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData0Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData0Box.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

        self.tData1Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData1Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData1Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData1Box.grid(row = 0, column = 4)

        self.tData2Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData2Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData2Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData2Box.grid(row = 0, column = 5)

        self.tData3Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData3Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData3Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData3Box.grid(row = 0, column = 7)

        self.tData4Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData4Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData4Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData4Box.grid(row = 0, column = 8)

        self.tData5Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData5Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData5Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData5Box.grid(row = 0, column = 9)

        self.tData6Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData6Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData6Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData6Box.grid(row = 0, column = 10)

        self.tData7Box = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tData7Box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tData7Box.insert(0,"FF")
        self.tData7Box.grid(row = 0, column = 11)

        self.tTimerBox = tk.Entry(window, width = 3)
        self.tTimerBox.pack(side="left", expand=True)
        self.tTimerBox.insert(0,"0")
        self.tTimerBox.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.tTimerBox.bind("<Return>",self.addToList)

        self.TranButton = tk.Button(window,
                                    text="Transmit",
                                    command = self.Enter)
        self.TranButton.pack(side="bottom")
        self.TranButton.grid(row = 1, column = 11)

        self.Translist = tk.Listbox(window,selectmode = "multiple", height =10, width = 50)
        self.Translist.pack(side = "bottom", expand = True)
        self.Translist.grid(row = 2, columnspan=11)

    def addToList(self,event):

        global transDict

        dictRef = len(transDict) + 1
        t = TransMsg()

        t.canID = self.IDbox.get()
        t.msgType = self.msgTypeBox.get()
        t.canType = self.canTypeBox.get()
        t.DLC = 8
        t.tData0 = self.tData0Box.get()
        t.tData1 = self.tData1Box.get()
        t.tData2 = self.tData2Box.get()
        t.tData3 = self.tData3Box.get()
        t.tData4 = self.tData4Box.get()
        t.tData5 = self.tData5Box.get()
        t.tData6 = self.tData6Box.get()
        t.tData7 = self.tData7Box.get()
        t.tTimer = self.tTimerBox.get()

        transDict[dictRef] = t

        self.Translist.insert("end","%d: %s %d %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d" %
                (dictRef,
                 transDict[dictRef].canID,
                 transDict[dictRef].DLC,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData0,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData1,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData2,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData3,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData4,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData5,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData6,
                 transDict[dictRef].tData7,
                 int(transDict[dictRef].tTimer)))

    def Enter(self):
        items = self.Translist.curselection()
        for i in items:
            print transDict[i].tTimer
            if transDict[i].tTimer <= 0:
                system('echo "sending: %s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s"' %
                        (transDict[i].msgType,
                         transDict[i].canType,
                         transDict[i].canID,
                         transDict[i].DLC,
                         transDict[i].tData0,
                         transDict[i].tData1,
                         transDict[i].tData2,
                         transDict[i].tData3,
                         transDict[i].tData4,
                         transDict[i].tData5,
                         transDict[i].tData6,
                         transDict[i].tData7))

            else:
                system('echo "sending: %s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s"' %
                        (transDict[i].msgType,
                         transDict[i].canType,
                         transDict[i].canID,
                         transDict[i].DLC,
                         transDict[i].tData0,
                         transDict[i].tData1,
                         transDict[i].tData2,
                         transDict[i].tData3,
                         transDict[i].tData4,
                         transDict[i].tData5,
                         transDict[i].tData6,
                         transDict[i].tData7))
                self.window.after(transDict[i].tTimer, self.Enter)



root = tk.Tk()

myapp = application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If anyone could have a look and see if it's just the way I am trying to access the dictionary or if there is a major mistake somewhere that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing `dictRef = len(transDict) + 1`, which makes `dictRef` start at 1. The Listbox indices however, start at 0. So when the first Listbox item is selected, `i` will be 0, but there is nothing with key 0 in the dictionary.
So either use `dictRef = len(transDict)` so `dictRef` is the same as the Listbox index (which I'd recommend) or put `i += 1` after `for i in items:` to compensate for the difference.

---

On a side note, please don't use both `pack` and `grid` on the same widgets, this makes absolutely no sense. `pack` and `grid` are two different geometry managers, so you can put a widget in the window with only one at a time.